# How to get list of elements that get updated dynamically when scrolling?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, discord.py

I'm trying to loop through the members list in discord, but this list only returns 22 member (membersSideBar), I think I need to scroll manually for this list to be full, but I don't know how, this is my Python code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("H:\Progs\Mz's Flash\Prog\Google Chrome\chromedriver_x86_v93.exe", options=o)

driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/753059977689694218/753059977689694222")

email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email.send_keys('abc@example.com')
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys('pa$$word')
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

membersSideBar = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "clickable-1JJAn8")))

for i in membersSideBar:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)
    i.click()
```

Comment: I know how to do this in ruby but not knowing how to do this in Python. But If I write the code, you could do the same in Python, I guess. But you have to give the username and password to see the membersSideBar.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I don't care about the language Ruby, C#, NodeJS, etc, I just want to know the mechanism for that, I can create a throwaway account for you to test, but maybe its easier if you show me how to do it in Ruby.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But clarify me something. Do you find a division something like with `overflow` for class attribute? `<div style="overflow:scroll; height:250px;">`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: Are you scrolling the webpage or are you scrolling the table?

Comment: I'm scrolling to the element itself, to bring it into view, that's what this JS code do:
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", i)`

Comment: Oh then your code is correct, It has to scroll down. Did you try the solution which pmadhu has written?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237869/discussion-between-captain-majid-and-rajagopalan).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and confirm:

Set a variable to keep track of `membersSideBar`.

In `While` loop `locate the Element` and keep `scrolling to the ith Element`.

On scrolling `membersSideBar` is updated with the new list of Elements.

And if no more Elements is found, `list out of bound` exception will be thrown so put the block of code in `try and except` block.

```
i = 0
try:
    while True:
        membersSideBar = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "clickable-1JJAn8")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", membersSideBar[i])
        time.sleep(2)
        i += 1
except:
    pass
```

Comment: I tried that, but due to the weird fetching of results, the 1st result returns 22 items, then while scrolling, it changes to random 33, 27, 36, etc.., so the items get repeated or ignored, maybe its an issue with discord only, I need to find a way to know where I'm, not to repeat or ignore any item.

Comment: Well try with different locators. Get a locator that highlights all the rows of that table.

Comment: I'm sure the locator is correct, the thing is with lists that get updated dynamically when scrolling, you can't get the whole list easily, you can try this with Youtube sidebar that shows related items, if you cut the internet or stopped scrolling, you won't get more items, I think this is called "lazy loading"; websites that have a long list of items, and to improve the initial loading speed it will only populate first 10 or 20 items from the list, and the rest will be dynamically added when the user scrolls down.